# SPARQL all predicate-object pairs of subject and all its superclasses

Tags: oop, inheritance, sparql, rdf, rdfs

Imagine you do something crazy and store your object-oriented model as an RDF graph.

[image: RDF Graph]

shows a simplified example of the inheritance hierarchy and the associated attributes.

In practice, you get [such graph structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1luAa.png) if you translate some UML class diagram into RDFS.

The question is: what SPARQL query can deliver all the predicate-object pairs necessary to instantiate a particular resource of "Class C". In other words: how do you get all the predicate-object pairs along the whole inheritance chain (only single inheritance).

Comment: Is it a homework assignment?

Comment: hehe.. unfortunately, times of homework are long gone. it's an actual real world problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the info from @scotthenninger the following query did the job:

```
SELECT ?p ?o
WHERE {
   :ClassC rdfs:subClassOf* ?anySuperClass .
   ?anySuperClass ?p ?o .   
}
```

edit:
Similar query gets all the self-defined properties and their range along the inheritance chain:

```
SELECT ?prop ?obj
    WHERE {
       :ClassC rdfs:subClassOf* ?anySuperClass .
       ?prop rdfs:domain ?anySuperClass .   
       ?prop rdfs:range ?obj .
}
```

End results combined:

```
foo:ID         xsd:string
foo:name       xsd:string
rdfs:comment   xsd:string
foo:similarTo  :ClassD
```

Comment: Good to see that you got some good ideas and was able to solve your problem - please consider voting @scotthenninger 's answer UP (if you found it useful) - then accept your own answer so that the question is marked as answered. Happy coding!

Comment: sure, but need +9 reputation to upvote scottheninger

Comment: Here's your missing reputation :)

Answer (score 4):

Given this diagram, the predicate-object pairs of all members of the class`:ClassC` is simply:

```
SELECT ?inst ?p ?o
WHERE {
   ?inst a :ClassC .
   Inst ?p ?o .
```

Keep in mind that there is not property inheritance in RDF/RDFS.  If you want to find all of property/values pairs for `ClassA` with entailments for subclasses then useL

```
SELECT ?inst ?p ?o
WHERE {
   ?cls rdfs:subClassOf* :ClassA .
   ?inst a ?cls .
   ?inst ?p ?o
}
```

In this respect, RDFS works a bit backwards of one's expectations of OO inheritance.

Comment: there is no instance data yet, just the TBox. But you gave me a good idea. `rdfs:subClassOf*` did the job.